# Attempted import error: '@firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'e')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-bootstrap

**I want to enable firestore for my react app.**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = firebase.firestore();

export default firebase;
```

**When I try to import firebase into a component like the following**

```
import firebase from 'fbconfig';
```

**I get the error message:**

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/esm5/index.js
Attempted import error: '@firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'e').
```

**The error shown on my browser is**

```
Failed to compile

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/esm5/index.js
Attempted import error: '@firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'e').

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Comment: Can you add the complete stack trace error that you are getting and also include the versions you have using of the Firebase SDK and services?

Comment: "firebase": "^8.10.0"

Failed to compile
./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/esm5/index.js
Attempted import error: '@firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'e').
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: Is this what you meant by stack trace error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, i use under solution. I change **“firebase/app” -> “firebase/compat/app”**. And this solve the problem. Because of firebase version, this problem arised.

// import firebase from 'firebase/app'; //old version

**import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; //v9**

Comment: I updated my firebase version to @9.1.3 by running $npm install firebase@9.1.3 and imported firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; and the app worked like a charm. Thank you so much.